# How can I make column name using argument name in a function in R?

Tags: r, arguments

This is a dataset.

```
require(data.table) 
df <- data.table(a = c(1, 2, 3),
b = c(4, 5, 6))
```

```
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 2 5
3: 3 6
```

I would like to make several several column names with my function.

Here is a example function.

```
f_test <- function(x){
  
  variableName <- eval(paste0("var_", x))
  
  df_1a <- df[, variableName := a * b *2 ]
}
```

For example, this is the expected outcome from `f_test("AAA")`

```
   a b var_AAA
1: 1 4     8
2: 2 5    20
3: 3 6    36
```

However, the function outcome is not 'var_AAA', but 'variableName'.
How do I assign the name based on the string argument in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might consider passing the whole data.table into the function, in addition to the character value containing the new column name. This might be better practice than changing a global environment object. Also, you can just use `paste0` to create the column name by reference with `:=`.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6))

f_test <- function(dt, var_name) {
  dt[ , paste0("var_", var_name) := a * b * 2]
  return(dt)
}

f_test(dt, "AAA")[]
```

**Output**

```
   a b var_AAA
1: 1 4       8
2: 2 5      20
3: 3 6      36
```

Comment: This is indeed better practice than my answer given below. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use `c()` in combination with the variableName:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table::data.table(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)

f_test <- function(x){
  variableName <- eval(paste0("var_", x))
  df[, c(variableName) := a * b *2 ][]
}

f_test("AAA")
```